# QMap always returning a const value

Tags: c++, qt, qmap, qstringlist

I have the following piece of code :

- classA.h

```
class A : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    private:
        QMap <QString , QStringList> map_filelist_hash ;
};
```

- classA.cpp

```
map_filelist_hash = { {"dummy"},{"dummylist"}};                 
QStringList& temp (map_filelist_hash["dummy"]);
```

I get the following error when trying to compile using gcc7.2.0

> **error:** cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘QStringList&’ to an rvalue of type ‘const QStringList’

How do I get `QMap` to return a reference of the `QStringList` inside the `QMap`?

Comment: You are probably writing this code in a `const` member function. Please make sure that your [mcve] code is complete - the `classA.cpp` will definitely not compile.

Comment: Yep. Didn't realize that all along.! Thanks for pointing out.